# How can I optimally group a list of objects by their sub object?

Tags: javascript, grouping, lodash, graphql

I'm trying to group some JavasScript objects by their shared similar object. I can do this effortlessly in Ruby, but for the life of my I (somewhat embarrassingly) can't figure this out in JS in linear time. JS doesn't seem to allow object literals as keys, at least for the purposes of reducing.

I have data shaped like this, as a result from a GraphQL query:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sheila',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tom',
    room: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bathroom'
    }
  }
]
```

In the UI, we're going to display the objects by the room they're in. We need to keep a reference to the room itself, otherwise we'd just sort by a room property.

What I'm trying to do is reshape the data into something like this:

```
{
  {id: 5, name: 'Kitchen'}: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'Sheila'}],
  {id: 3, name: 'Bathroom'}: [{id: 2, name: 'Tom'}]
}
```

As you can see, the people are grouped together by the room they're in.

It could also be shaped like this...

```
[ 
  { room: {id: 5, name: 'Kitchen'}, people: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob', ...}] }, 
  { room: {id: 3, name: 'Bathroom', people: [{id: 2, name: 'Tom'}]
]
```

However it comes out, we just need the people grouped by the rooms in linear time.

I've tried lodash's `groupBy`, using both `map` and `reduce`, just doing `for` loops that put the list together, etc. I'm stumped because without being able to use an object literal (the room) as a hash index, I don't know how to efficiently group the outer objects by the inner objects.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: adding clarity about trying to do it with linear time complexity - the most efficient equivalent of this Ruby code:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
value.each_with_object(h) { |v, m| m[v[:room]] << v }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) and [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to gather and transform each group. Additionally, we use [`lodash#omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omit) to remove the `room` object from each `person` from the `people` array.

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('room.id')
  .map(people => ({
    room: { ...people[0].room }, 
    people: _.map(people, person => _.omit(person, 'room'))
  })).value();
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sheila',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tom',
    room: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bathroom'
    }
  }
];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('room.id')
  .map(people => ({
    // make sure to create a new room object reference
    // to avoid mutability
    room: { ...people[0].room }, 
    people: _.map(people, person => _.omit(person, 'room'))
  })).value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, great stuff! I like the clever use of the `groupBy` before `map` then using the first element of the array to access the room. I knew there had to be some way to build a combinator via lodash. Here's what I landed on: `_(data.stuff).groupBy('room.id').map(people => ({room: people[0].room, people})).value()` (The room copy-spread isn't necessary for us as the values come from Apollo and are immutable already. We also didn't want to remove the room, just group by them.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to create an object of people indexed by rooms and then get that object's `values`, no library needed:

```js
const input=[{id:1,name:'Bob',room:{id:5,name:'Kitchen'}},{id:3,name:'Sheila',room:{id:5,name:'Kitchen'}},{id:2,name:'Tom',room:{id:3,name:'Bathroom'}}]

const output = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, { id, name, room }) => {
    const roomName = room.name;
    if (!a[roomName]) a[roomName] = { room, people: [] };
    a[roomName].people.push({ id, name });
    return a;
  }, {})
);
console.log(output);
```

Objects like

```
{id: 5, name: 'Kitchen'}: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'Sheila'}],
```

in your question can't be properties like that unless the structure is a `Map`. Ordinary Javascript objects can only have string (/ number) properties.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use `reduce` in order to groupBy the rooms.

```js
const input = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sheila',
    room: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Kitchen'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tom',
    room: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bathroom'
    }
  }
];

const res = input
  .map(person => ({
    person: {
      id: person.id,
      name: person.name
    },
    room: person.room
  }))
  .reduce((rooms, person) => {
    const room = rooms.find(room => room.id === person.room.id) || 
      { room: person.room };
    const idx = rooms.indexOf(room);

    room.people = room.people ?
      [...room.people, person.person] :
      [person.person];

    return Object.assign(rooms, {
      [idx === -1 ? rooms.length : idx]: room
    });
  }, []);

console.log(res);
```